# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()" because "com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN" is null

Tags: karate

Hello karate experts,

I see the below error while trying to execute karate tests from IntelliJ.

```
*<ServiceName>*.ParallelRunner > testParallel FAILED
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.tagSelector(Runner.java:80)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner.parallel(Runner.java:309)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.parallel(Runner.java:190)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner.parallel(Runner.java:218)
        at com.intuit.karate.Runner.parallel(Runner.java:214)
        at *<ServiceName>*.ParallelRunner.testParallel(ParallelRunner.java:30)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()" because "com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN" is null
            at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.createBindings(ScriptBindings.java:160)
            at com.intuit.karate.core.Tags.<init>(Tags.java:158)
            at com.intuit.karate.core.Tags.<clinit>(Tags.java:48)
            ... 6 more

1 test completed, 1 failed
Finished generating test XML results (0.006 secs) into: /Users/*<empId>*/*<ServiceName>*/build/test-results/acceptanceTests
Generating HTML test report...
Finished generating test html results (0.005 secs) into: /Users/*<empId>*/*<ServiceName>*/build/reports/tests/acceptanceTests

> Task :acceptanceTests FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The karate version I'm using is testImplementation **'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:0.9.6'** and *java version is 17*. Could somebody please suggest the best way to resolve this error ?

The below command with the necessary credentials passed is used to execute tests is

```
./gradlew clean acceptanceTest -Dkarate.clientId='<>' \                                                                                                                           ─╯
-Dkarate.clientSecret='<>' \
-Dkarate.abTestMgmt='<>' \
-Dkarate.env='<>' -Dkarate.options="--tags @CRUD_ConfigurationId" --info
```

Below is the paralleRunner file

```
package *<serviceName>*;

import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;

@Slf4j
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@newFeature", "~@ignore", "~@50Test"})
public class ParallelRunner {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 10);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "*ServiceName*_AcceptanceTest");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }

}
```

An upgrade in karate version might help but the project uses junit4 for integration and unit tests. What would be the best thing to move forward?

I tried upgrading the karate version to latest release but saw lot of errors in integration and unit tests because of the junit dependency used.Thanks !!

Comment: the best way ? upgrade. you are using a very very old version of karate that is not supported. tell this to your leadership if needed. if you have not been keeping track of releases, you have to read all the release notes. karate has a reputation of minimal breaking changes, but there are some. you will need to invest time in a migration